# Why my anwsers were deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

In the past I used a PHP library to detect the Web Browser used by my end users (not to serve content - I use feature detection for that). Since the library I used became abandonware, I decided to rewrite it and add new features and support a lot more browsers/robots.

Since my library is better (IMHO) than the one I used in the past, I wanted people to use my library (it's free, open source and uses GNU Lesser General Public License 3+). I thought I could go answer all the question that could be solved by my library. So I did search on SO and answered these questions.

My answers always answered the actual question with a full example, explanation and a link to the library. Yes some were similar but they always were legit answers (not just a shameless plug).

I found out that all those answers were deleted by an admin. I guess they were flagged for some reasons but I think these are false positives. Is there anyone that can check that for me and tell me is there is something wrong about what I did?

This is an [example question where my anwser was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780188/reliable-way-to-detect-browser-version-and-plattfom-in-php).

It took me several hours to find and answer those questions and I think they are 100% legit. Please educate me if I'm wrong and if not please undelete them :)

Comment: You've found questions that should be closed.  Congrats.  I'm sure mods will be along soon to close them and delete the awful ones.

Comment: I imagine that the fact that no disclosure is made about you being the author of the library may have something to do with that.

Comment: You know only users with 10k+ rep can see deleted posts? A screen grab or quoted answer would be useful if you want your answer to be judged.

Comment: Your answers aren't good, because they're not addressing the general question. Your answer is "(You must use this library, and then) You can...". You also do not disclose your affiliation with the library as its sole author. This is not a "promote my project as the only solution" site. If you posted a *generic* solution that did not use your library, and then added "Of course, if you use my XYZ open source library, you could just do ..." as an alternative, it would be fine. What you're doing now is "Use XYZ library as the only possible solution", which of course it isn't.

Comment: OK I see the point of promotion and will reword these answers and tell I'm the author. I'm just trying to understand what I did wrong to correct myself and not repeat the same mistake in the future. I'm not trying to sell anything on the contrary. It took a lot of time to put this together and I'm giving away all of this.

Answer (score 12):

You left 16 answers in a row, all promoting the same project, none with any disclosure that you were the author of this project. Many of these questions already had many answers, and some of your answers didn't seem to specifically target the questions asked.

These were all flagged as spam, and a moderator removed them as a result. I removed the spam flags on a few of them that were tripping up reviewers, but I deferred to the moderator who deleted them in the first place and left them deleted.

I'm usually more lenient with answers that point to someone's open source project than ones that link to commercial products, but this seemed a little excessive to me. I don't know if I would have deleted them myself, but I saw no reason to overrule the moderator who did.

For starters, you really do need to disclose your involvement with the project. That's important information, and may color someone's perception of your answer. Second, I wouldn't search for questions that you can answer with your project and shotgun answers to those. Third, I'd make sure each answer was crafted to the question it is addressing.

If you can edit in proper disclosure to your answers, and make whatever other fixes are needed to improve the points I described above, flag your answers as you improve them and we'll look at undeleting them.

Comment: I will make sure to review them but as far as I remember they answered the question and even more. I will point out that I'm the author you are right this must be transparent. But I don't understand what's bad about searching for questions that I can answer... I guess I it was for commercial gain I would understand the issue, but I'm just trying to help. How can I find all those deleted answers so I can review them? Thanks for your input.

Comment: How can I find all those deleted answers so I can review them? Thanks for your input?

Comment: @AlexV - If you go to your profile and bring up your answers, there should be a link at the bottom of the list for "deleted recent answers" or something like that to show these.

Comment: I got the link but I get "No deleted recent answers"

Comment: Is there another way to find them?